# How do I specify a set of tests using VSTest in a Pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, vstest

Using azure pipelines I want to build and run web service tests.
Using the **classic** pipeline builder (so not the YAML) I want to be able to select a specific set of tests to run. My tests are grouped into various classes. Each class has numerous tests.

If I leave the filter field empty I will run all tests in all classes.
But I would like to specify a class of tests. How do I do this?

I have tried the following but no tests can be found

**ClassName=WebServices.SocialTests**

**ClassName=SocialTests**

**Tests=SocialTests**

or

**Tests=WebServices.SocialTests**

Using Jenkins, I can run these tests from the command line. All I have to do is specify the following:

**dotnet vstest mytests.dll /Tests:SocialTests**

So the question is why can i not do it in a pipeline?

Comment: try `Name=SocialTests`

Comment: How about adding TestCategory, filter: `TestCategory=CategoryA` , then runs tests which are annotated with `[TestCategory("CategoryA")]`?

Comment: I was not using categories. But I added them and they work OK.

Comment: Using "Name=" works for a single test in a class. Not for all tests in that class.

Comment: @jpc It seems that using TestCategory can work, I will post this as a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As workaround , you can add TestCategory to the test method , for example: `--filter TestCategory=CategoryA` , runs tests which are annotated with [TestCategory("CategoryA")].

```
namespace MSTestNamespace
{
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTestClass1
    {
        [Priority(2)]
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1(){
        
        }

        [TestCategory("CategoryA")]
        [Priority(3)]
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod2(){
        }
    }
}
```

For details , please refer to this [document](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/filter.md#examples).